# Unicode characters encoding bug on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, unicode, encoding

When I type in the town name (Stuttgart) then remove the mouse focus from the input box (click elsewhere), the look-up algorithm replaces the town name with what you see below.

Should be easy to fix:

- most likely `HtmlEncode()` is where it shouldn't be
- or perhaps new server tags `<%: %>` screw it, then switch back to good old `<%= %>`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks! We've fixed the encoding issue.

Comment: Great job, guys!